# How to create a unique id for a new created user in Django

Tags: django

I have been using a custom user model for my Django user model. Now, I want to create a new member for the model "uuid" which will be a random long unique string for every new user and users that have been created before. How can I do that in model.py ?

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

    class User(AbstractUser):
        bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
        language = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default="en-gb")
        location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
        birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        picture = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
        is_custom_picture = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: This will not fulfill your "long" criteria, but every object has a unique id, for example, if `a` is an instance of `User` then you can access the `id` of that object by saying `a.id`

Comment: "Long" criteria is required. That is correct id is unique but short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another field inside your django model called uniqueID

```
import uuid
uniqueID = models.UUIDField(max_length=255, default = uuid.uuid4)
```

You could also initialize this to act as the primary_key of your model using `primary_key=True` argument inside the field constructor.

Comment: When I add this to the model, will this be created for the user created before ?

Comment: No, but it should create fields for the pre existing models when you run the migrate and makemigrations commands.

Comment: So this will create the field, but they are not going to be unique for the previous users, but can be default.

Comment: It is indeed going to be unique for every instance of the model. Whether old or new ones created.